# Make autodiscover work for second Exchange domain

Tags: exchange, autodiscover

We have Active Directory, Domain Controller and Exchange server 2019 for `abc.com`. They are all behind NAT and all services (Autodiscover, ActiveSync, OWA, ...) work properly.

We also need to have email service for `xyz.com` too, so this is what we've done so far:

**External DNS**

`mail` and `autodiscover` of `xyz.com` point to the same public IP address of `abc.com`.

**Internal DNS**

`mail` and `autodiscover` of `xyz.com` point to the same Exchange server as of `abc.com`.

**Active Directory**

`xyz.com` is defined as alternative UPN suffix in the properties of Active Directory Domains and Trusts.

**Exchange Server**

`xyz.com` is defined in the Accepted Domains of Exchange Server -> Mail Flow. Some email accounts are created with `@xyz.com`.

However, Autodiscover is not working for `xyz.com` email accounts. All clients we have tried fail to detect the server settings.

Again, Autodiscover works fine for main domain which is `abc.com`.

What we are trying to do is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create the srv record.

I will create SRV record in abc.com DNZ zone, and all Autodiscover queries for xyz.com domain will be redirected to autodiscover.abc.com.

You could check this case
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/97baf014-d036-47d2-8b97-24da1232aa53/autodiscover-dns-records-for-multiple-domain-names?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaging